# NSArray initwithArray: crash

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad

I get crash with the following code and unable to figure out what was the error. The following is the code

```
.h file
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *SelectedDayTimings;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *arrTimings;

.m file
-(void)loadData{

self.SelectedDayTimings = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[self GetTimings:"Id" date:date  DId:[[array objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"Id"]  OrderType:[[array objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"Type"] ZId:[[array objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"ZId"]  TotalDistance:[[array objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"TotalDistance"]]copyItems:YES];
}


-(NSMutableArray*)GetTimings:(NSString*)LocId date:(NSDate*)date DId:(NSString*)strId  OrderType:(NSString*)strType ZId:(NSString*)strId  TotalDistance:(NSString*)strTotalDistance
{
     NSMutableArray *array1=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

      // Add objects to array1 from server
    arrTimings=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:array1];
    return arrTimings;

}
```

I get crash with the following

[image]

Any idea/help will be appreciated

Comment: arrTimings is not declared. Also you unit SelectedDayTiming with an array of array of the return of getTimîngs which already return an nsmutablearray

Comment: @PtitXav I have declared arrTimings array , plz chk . Could you please let me know what do you mean by this "Also you unit SelectedDayTiming with an array of array of the return of getTimîngs which already return an nsmutablearray"

Comment: Why are you showing only the beginning of the stack trace? Which line of code causes the crash?

Comment: In GetTimings you create an array (from another array) and you return it. Then you unit self.SelectedDayTimimgs with an array initialized with the array returned by grtTimings. Why not self.SelectedDayTimings = [self GetTimimgs(…)] ?